# Задача на методы обьектов

Tags: javascript

**Нужно написать метод так, чтобы он удалял элементы из массива в свойстве объекта.**

*Рекомендации к выполнению:*

Объявлена переменная atTheOldToad.

Значение свойства atTheOldToad.potions это массив ["Speed potion", "Dragon breath", "Stone skin"].

После первого вызова метода atTheOldToad.removePotion("Dragon breath"), в свойстве potions будет массив ["Speed potion", Stone skin"].

После второго вызова метода atTheOldToad.removePotion("Speed potion"), в свойстве potions будет массив ["Stone skin"].

**Я написал такой код:**

```
    const atTheOldToad = {
  potions: ["Speed potion", "Dragon breath", "Stone skin"],
  removePotion(potionName) { 
    return this.potions.splice(this.potions.indexOf(potionName, 1));
  },
};
```

[image: Но программа проверки не пропускает:]

Пробовал разные варианты со "splice" и  с "pop" и с "shift". Ничего не получается. (Я только учусь:) )

Comment: так вы можете самостоятельно вызывать метод и посмотреть, что осталось в переменной?

Comment: там бы число удаляемых элементов как параметр метода тоже не мешало бы добавить, ну или скобку в правильное место ткнуть. Скорее второе, вряд ли вам интересен поиск не с начала массива

Comment: ```splice``` - return value - массив, содержащий удалённые элементы

Comment: вместо передачи второго параметра в `indexOf`: `splice(this.potions.indexOf(potionName, 1))` надо было передать в `splice`: `splice(this.potions.indexOf(potionName), 1)`. Также неплохо было бы проверить вариант, когда элемента в массиве нет. В текущем коде ты просто удалишь последний элемент из массива.

Comment: Ничего не понятно...   Какой алгоритм работы метода? Где об этом почитать? Метод удаляет элемент. А дальше? При втором вызове?     return this.potions.splice(potionName, 1); - пишет что правильно сделано для варианта после второго вызова.  return this.potions.splice(1, 1); - пишет что правильно сделано для варианта после первого вызова. А как реализовать вместе? Распишите, если не сложно, как оно работает. Что за чем делает... Совсем запутался. По теории читаю и ничего применить не могу(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d4n5x7tq/

Comment: К сожалению, не работает     const atTheOldToad = {
  potions: ["Speed potion", "Dragon breath", "Stone skin"],
  removePotion(potionName) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.potions.length; i += 1) {
    if (potionName === this.potions[i].name) {
      this.potions.splice (i, 1)
    }
  }
  },
};
console.log(atTheOldToad.removePotion("Dragon breath"))
console.log(atTheOldToad.removePotion("Speed potion"))                Я так попробовал, но тоже ругается проверка:(